# PHP FILE HANDLING ERROR - Unable to figure out

Tags: php, file

```
function Random_N() {
    $RandomNumber = mt_rand(1, 9999); 
    return 'temp_file/$RandomNumber.html';
}

global $file_name;
$file_name=Random_N();          


$file = fopen($file_name, 'w+');
$text=$msg1;
fwrite($file, $text);

$_SESSION['body']=$msg1;
$_SESSION['file_name1']=$file_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for starters - some explanation about the problem is much appreciated. You'll find you will get a lot more assistance if don't just expect everyone to read your code and determine for themselves what you're trying to do.

In your code, this line: `$text = $msg1` might be a source of your problem. Where did `$msg1` come from?

In the `Random_N` function, it will always return the string `'temp_file/$RandomNumber.html'` because it is enclosed in single quotes. Either change to double quotes, or preferably, use some concatenation:

```
return 'temp_file/' . $RandomNumber . '.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Random_N() {
$RandomNumber = mt_rand(1, 9999); 
return "temp_file/$RandomNumber.html";
}
```

Try above, you had put a variable inside single quotes which has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake i think so, see this function

```
function Random_N() {
$RandomNumber = mt_rand(1, 9999); 
return 'temp_file/$RandomNumber.html';
}
```

$RandomNumber is a variable. return function you used will not return the correct value it return value for $RandomNumber.html. Concatenate correctly.

instead of `return 'temp_file/$RandomNumber.html'`

type `return 'temp_file/'.$RandomNumber.'.html'`